# ISO 8601 date format to Unix Time in Java

Tags: java, date, unix, time, iso

I have done some Googling and Stacking, but cannot find the necessary resources for any methods that can convert ISO-8601 format to Unix time in Java.

I am parsing NOAA's (National Oceanic Atmospheric Administration) predictions, and using XPath I am able to successfully parse that data. I would, however, like to convert the ISO-8601 i.e. `2013-10-31T14:00:00-07:00` date format to Unix time.

Are there any Java libraries that can do this?

What my code does:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempHourlyResult.getLength(); i++) {
                writer.append(
                        hourlyResult.item(i).getNodeValue() + ","
                        + tempHourlyResult.item(i).getNodeValue()+ "," 
                        + dewPointResult.item(i).getNodeValue() + ","
                        + windSpeedResult.item(i).getNodeValue() +","
                        + relHumResult.item(i).getNodeValue() + "\n");
            }
```

Comment: "The ISO-8601 date format" actually narrows it down much less than you'd think!  Do you mean you want a parser that understands anything that is compliant with the standard, or you just need to read a specific format?

Comment: Edited my original post to clarify =). Provided an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.util.Date` class store time internally in a format very close to the POSIX time format (it uses milliseconds instead of seconds).  So assuming you have your date in a `String` object called `stringDate`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
long dateInMilli = dateParser.parse(stringDate).getTime();
long posixDate = dateInMilli/1000
```

Comment: Excuse - what is `dateParser`? What I have currently is in the format of `relativeHumidityResult.item(i).getNodeValue()` which outputs to the ISO-8601 format.

Comment: I edited for clarity, I admit it was not explicit enough

Comment: Thanks @Francis, however, what do I need to add to include the timezone as well? The format is -7 in my example.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssXXX` would include the timezone in all its full 8601 glory.

Comment: `Z` doesn't include the colon that the OP has in the example date. Shouldn't it be `XXX` per that API doc?

Comment: Oh you guys =). This is the one that worked `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`. Using `Z` gave me an `unparseable` error.

Comment: I confirm, just tested on my computer.  However `SimpleDateFormat` does not seem to document `XXX`.  In anycase I updated the answer.

Comment: Don't forget that `.getTime()` gives milliseconds, while POSIX is seconds.

Comment: Is it alright that I don't cast it to the `long` type?

Comment: Very true Dmitri, thanks for the observation.  I updated accordingly.

Comment: As I am doing something that requires an `i`, and I cannot cast to `long` every time the loop runs again, is it alright if I don't cast it to `long`?

Comment: @Francis, it looks like `XXX` was added to the API in JRE 7 and is doc'd [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Francis and dcsohl you two are too cute!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by requiring an `i` and not casting to a `long`. Your `i` is separate from the result of this parsing business, isn't it? At any rate, if you do the division by 1000 to get seconds you should be OK casting it to an `int` until 2038. But I wouldn't advise doing this.